# PHP: the id number is cut out, and remain only the first number

Tags: php

I am making a little CMS. I am currently working on editing the pages. It works properly, but only if the 'id' of the page is less the 10 (has only 1 number)

This is the link the send to the edit_page with the form prepopulated with the proper content:

```
<a href="edit_page.php?nav_id_trough_link=<?php echo urlencode($selected_nav['id']); ?>">Edit this page</a> </p>
```

(sorry for the clumsy name of nav_id_trough_link, is just that i am learning)

When i just visit the page, in the address bar there is this:

```
http://localhost:8080/test1again/backend.php?navv=39
```

but when i click on the edit link, bringing me to edit_page.php, in the address bar appear this:

```
http://localhost:8080/test1again/edit_page.php?nav_id_trough_link=3
```

Somehow it cut out the 9
The same happen if the id of the page is 40, then will become 4 (and prepopulating the form with the content of the page that has the id 4..)

Someone please know why this can happen?

Comment: nope. we can't help. not enough information. do some debugging yourself. `var_dump($selected_nav)` to see what you're dealing with, then work your way back the chain to see where the digits are being lost. for all we know, maybe this isn't a php problem - there could be a bad mod_rewrite rule mangling things completely out of php's view.

Comment: if you're sure `$selected_nav['id']` is always a numeric value, you don't have to `urlencode` it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error clearly lies in:

```
<?php echo urlencode($selected_nav['id']); ?>
```

Are you sure `$selected_nav` is an array? It looks like `$selected_nav` is a string, you are accessing it like an array and since string can be accessed as array but using only numercial indexes, `'id'` is casted to int (`0`) and first character is returned.

Comment: That is beauty, so well spotted. +1

Comment: There speaks the voice of bitter experience I think :)

Comment: Thank you dev-null-dweller!!
It was as you said!

i changed into:
    <a href="edit_page.php?nav_id_trough_link=<?php echo $selected_nav; ?>">Edit this page</a> </p>

And now is working fine!!

This community is very efficient!!